# A C# desktop application that raised Toast Notification on win 8.1 stopped raising them after an upgrade to win 10

Tags: c#, toast

I have a c# desktop application that raises Toast Notification, it is built using visual studio 2013.
On win 8.1 all is ok, after an upgrade to win 10 the application still works except for the Toast Notifications that are no longer getting raised.

The code that I use for the Toast Notification

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(_appId).Show(toast);
```

it references:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd

and for the Windows.winmd reference, I added to the .csproj file the Property: `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>`

Should this still work on windows 10? If so what can be the problem?

Comment: Do you fulfill these requirements? "For a desktop app to display a toast, the app must have a shortcut on the Start screen. The shortcut must have an AppUserModelID."

Comment: Yes, I used the samples that use MS.WindowsAPICodePack.Internal to create it, and it was ok on win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, so I’ll share my actions and non-proven theory.
For the toast to work it has to have a shortcut on the start screen and have an appId mapped to it, and later you create a toast notifier passing that appid:

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(_appId).Show(toast);
```

I deleted the shortcut changed the appid and recreated the shortcut, and it worked, probably just changing the appid should be enough.
My non-proven theory: 
The original code should also work on windows 10 and the problem was the upgrade. 
The shortcut and the appId were created on win 8.1 and during the upgrade to win 10 got changed\ corrupted, but still existed somewhere (some cache, registry...), and that caused the problem, so creating a new appid after the upgrade solve it.